# How to pass list to method and insert element?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I am beginner learning Java and trying to create a method for list to add elements in the list and return the list. But getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> language cannot be resolved at karl_language.language(karl_language.java:14) at karl_language.main(karl_language.java:33)

```
public class karl_language {
    
    public boolean isEmpty(List<String> language) {
        if(language.isEmpty())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    public List<String> language(String languages){
        language.add(languages);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        karl_language lan = new karl_language();
        List<String> language = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of languages : ");
        int n = input1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the language : ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            language.add(input1.next());
        }
        System.out.println(language);
        System.out.println("Is List Empty? : "+lan.isEmpty(language));
        System.out.println("Enter the number of languages need to be added :");
        int n1 = input1.nextInt();
        for(int i =0 ; i<n1 ;i++) {
            lan.language(input1.next());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you got

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 language cannot be resolved

 at karl_language.language(karl_language.java:14)
 at karl_language.main(karl_language.java:33)

Comment: as i see your main method is inside the karl_language class and you want to create an instance of it and run into main.get main method out and put it in another class then try.

Comment: In your method named `language`, you use a variable named `language`. There is no such variable in scope in that method.

Comment: public void addlanguage(String languages,List<String> language){
  language.add(languages);
 }

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer..Previously i didnt define the method properly [ addlanguage ].Thanks for your help!!

```
public class karl_language {
    
    public boolean isEmpty(List<String> language) {
        if(language.isEmpty())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    
    public void addlanguage(String languages,List<String> language){
        language.add(languages);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        karl_language lan = new karl_language();
        List<String> language = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of languages : ");
        int n = input1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the language : ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            language.add(input1.next());
        }
        System.out.println(language);
        System.out.println("Is List Empty? : "+lan.isEmpty(language));
        System.out.println("Enter the number of languages need to be added :");
        int n1 = input1.nextInt();
        for(int i =0 ; i<n1 ;i++) {
            lan.addlanguage(input1.next(),language);
        }
        System.out.println(language);
        input1.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey saranya s. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, consider detailing what the answer you got was and how your problem was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).